# How to extract the raw generic type out of generic type with type parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

Assume I have an generic type of an runtime object and a raw generic type of the same class, e.g.

```
var type = (new List<Int32>()).GetType();
var genericListType = typeof(List<>);
```

I need kind of `GetRawGenericType` method, so the expression

```
GetRawGenericType(type) == genericListType
```

returns true. Is there a way to implement this ?

**Remarks:**

I do not know the type of the of the object it may be any generic type.
In the code I'm writing I have to know the exact generic type as it will be used as a key in a Dictionary, for example :

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, TValue> Mapping = 
    new Dictionary<Type, TValue> { 
            {typeof(IEnumerable<>), *SomeValue*},
            ...
        }
```

Thanks in advance for you time spend.

Comment: btw your first line could be simply `var type = typeof(List<int>);`

Comment: @AakashM: If the type in the first line is actually known, then the entire question is pointless. It's probably something like `var type = someObjectSentToAMethod.GetType();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition) is what you looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`GetGenericTypeDefinition` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx):

```
var type = (new List<Int32>()).GetType();
var genericListType = typeof(List<>);

Console.WriteLine(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericListType);
```

shows

```
true
```